# Why does Javascript in a Form Element Fail?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I recently bashed my ahead against a wall while troubleshooting a JS app; it boiled down to something like this: putting the js in a form html element causes it to fail/immediately reverse. Why is this?

FAILS:

```
<div id="p1">Hello World!</div>
<form>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="New text!";'>Change me</button
</form>
```

WORKS:

```
<div id="p1">Hello World!</div>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="New text!";'>Change me</button
```

Comment: you are posting the form so the page is reloading, you need to add `return false;` into the onclick

Comment: I think it was really a bad idea to make the `<button>` element default to `type="submit"` ... just my 2cents

Comment: @devnull69 The default behavior of a button inside a form is `submit`...

Comment: Yes ... that's what I said (at least that's what I meant). It's a really bad idea to make "submit" the default behavior of <button> elements

Comment: If you want a `button` not to submit the form, then add `type="button"` to it.

Comment: Granted ... it's like saying "I want a simple button ... yes, I am sure I really want a simple button" `<button type="button">`

Comment: Buttons that absolutely depend on JavaScript are a terrible idea. Having them as submit buttons is a sensible default.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<div id="p1">Hello World!</div>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
<button onclick='document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="New text!";'>Change me</button>
</form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDKdT/8/)